# Showing all the entries inside a SharePoint Multiple line of text which have append changes to exsisting text enabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi

I have the following field inside my SharePoint list:-

[image: paint.png]

inside SharePoint view when we click on an item we can view all the entries inside the above field along with the date and the username.. but if we link the list with power bi then is there a way to view all the entries (as in the SharePoint view case)? currently only the latest entry will appear inside power bi report.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Power BI yet, but what if you copy the text to a normal Multi Lines of text field?  Can you see it in your report?

As workaround, I'm thinking you could configure a simple workflow to auto-copy the text from your current field to a multi line of plain text field which you would use in your Power BI report.  You'd need to set the workflow to run after every modification of the field.  My thinking being that perhaps Power BI won't work with an 'append changes' field.

Comment: thanks for your email, i will look into this workaround if i can not get things working on power bi as expected